# Conditional join from different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like
`Items`:

```
id   index
1     45
1     50
2     25
2     45
```

I am writing a query that 
select all rows from `items`. I need to replace the index with its description.
Id 1 indicates table_a, id 2 indicates table_b.

Table_A

```
index   description
45          'ddd'
50          'fff'
```

Table_B

```
index   description
25          'AAA'
45          'BBB'
```

meaning I need to join on index but depending on id.

something like:

```
Select id,index,description
from items
join table_A,table_B using (index)
```

What I want to get is:

```
id index description

1    45    'ddd'
1    50    'fff'
2    25    'AAA'
2    45    'BBB'
```

How can I do that with 1 Join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to UNION Table_A & Table_B first, then join with Items as follows

```
Select id,index,T.description from items
join (select 1 as id, index, description from Table_A 
UNION select 2 as id, index, description from Table_B) as T
ON items.id=T.id and items.index=T.index
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that UNION doesn't count as a join, then:

```
SELECT i.id, i.index, u.description
  FROM Items AS i
  JOIN (SELECT 1 AS id, index, description FROM Table_A
        UNION
        SELECT 2 AS id, index, description FROM Table_B
       ) AS u
    ON u.id = i.id AND i.index = u.index;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using a single join statement.

`select a.id_,a.indx,
decode(a.id_,1,(select description from table_a where indx=a.indx),
             2,(select description from table_b where indx=a.indx)) description
from item a`

It will give the desired output. But i think `indx=a.indx` will act as Anti-Join(type of implicit join).

Any how only one select statement will execute in every iteration inside decode.
So only one join at a time.

Please current me if I'm wrong.